# How Insert 50K records to Oracle database?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I have requirement to only insert some data to Oracle database to only one table and not any relationships.

I need to insert more than `50K` records in the same transaction. What is the best way to do this?  Using pure `JDBC`, `JPA` or `Hibernate` etc…

Which way (batch update or raw by raw update) is better to insert the around 50000 record in same transaction?

Comment: You can go with some batch processing.

Comment: 50k records is tiny, anything can do it. What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: Which API is better? Pure JDBC or JPA...

Comment: Since you want to ``INSERT`` data only (no object orientation required), you'd be best off with JDBC, I suppose. But technically anything will do.

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate : using batch update you can insert your data,

1. First save all object in session

   `session.save(Object);`
2. `flush()` and `clear()` your session

> ```
> if ((batchCounter % 25000) == 0) {
>   session.flush();
>   session.clear();
> }
> ```

3. Commit all the data

   `tx.commit();`

Comment: Which API is best? Pure JDBC or JPA etc...

Comment: JPA is good api to work with, suppose in feature your database get changed.... JPA will help you....It also have various advantages...

Answer (score 1):

you can use Java Jdbc prepared statement.

```
// Create SQL statement
String SQL = "INSERT INTO Employee (id, first, last, age) " +
             "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";

// Create PreparedStatement object
PreparedStatemen pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);

// Set auto-commit to false
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

// Set the variables
pstmt.setInt( 1, 400 );
pstmt.setString( 2, "x" );
pstmt.setString( 3, "y" );
pstmt.setInt( 4, 33 );

// Add it to the batch
pstmt.addBatch();

// Set the variables
pstmt.setInt( 1, 401 );
pstmt.setString( 2, "p" );
pstmt.setString( 3, "q" );
pstmt.setInt( 4, 31 );

// Add it to the batch
pstmt.addBatch();

// Create an int[] to hold returned values
int[] count = stmt.executeBatch();

// Explicitly commit statements to apply changes
conn.commit();
```

Comment: Which API is best? Pure JDBC or JPA etc...

Comment: it is decided depending on the requirement. If your project has hibernate, then go with it.